# Firebase seems to save names based on local devices

Tags: android, angularjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, galaxy

First of all, not sure where to post this on the Stack community.

I am creating an app, which suppose to be responsive, see: [pedecabra.ideacodinglab.com](http://pedecabra.ideacodinglab.com/)
When I save to Firebase, from different devices, it creates the same collection twice, it supposes not to happen. But...just warned the user to use the same device. But now, when I try to erase from the computer, I cannot erase from a computer what was created on my device: Android 11, Galaxy A3.

This an example, there are two Jorge Guerra Pires, which supposes not to happen, two collections with same name. When I try to erase, it does not recognize the name. I have done copy&paste from the other collection, where it recognized.

[image]

My theory: Firebase saves name based on local information, from the device. For us humans, it is transformed into strings, but the compute compares strings based on local operation system

I have done a research on Google, using searching sentences such as "same strings on different operation systems are different".

Discussion

"they are no longer existing just ont the device(s). " it saved locally the name, and also on the database. You can access from the same device, even after closing the app. But just the app can access the collection it created.

" It sounds like there is a difference between the names, like for example some whitespace or non-printable characters. "

tried manually, enter the caracter. Even the automatic access, from the app, just get what it created, even though they exist

See the several duplicates, which should not exist. I wanted the same nickname be accessable from several devices.

[image]

Same problem, typed manually, and tried copy&paste
[image]

Comment: If the collections show up in the Firebase console, they are no longer existing just ont the device(s). It sounds like there is a difference between the names, like for example some whitespace or non-printable characters. But it's hard to say where that comes from without seeing a minimal repro, or at the very least the exact, complete copy/paste value of the duplicate collection names.

Comment: It happens in other names, it is not specific from this name. I will add more example! But I will check what you said, regarding space. I did not think about it!

Comment: Added more details, I have checked, did manually, same problems! 

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, it was space. Somehow, Android is giving a small space at the end. It is quite subtle. Should I keep the question. Maybe somebody else may run into the same issue. It is quite annoying! thanks  I will have to create a processing routine to eliminitate this space, if I can.

Comment: It worked! I have found a simple trick to eliminate spaces, just to make sure, added a huge space, and it works! 

Comment: Good to hear you found it Jorge!  This type of typo is not something that someone in the same situation is going to find going forward, so I vote to close the question as a type of ephemeral problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that somewhere, no idea where, a small space was introduced in the end: it was just introduced in one device, I have already fixed, no idea which one.

So:
Collection #1: Jorge Guerra Pires/
Collection #2: Jorge Guerra Pires /

They were different. I have to give a small space to erase.

On the code:

```
this.store.collection(this.username.replace(/\s+/g, '')).add({ "timestamp": this.timestamp, "sentimentos": aux });
```

I have added in the end of username, before without: `replace(/\s+/g, '')`

Thus, I just had to make sure wherever the space was coming from, it would be eliminated before creating or accessing the Firebase collection.

Tried several space, to make sure

Now I can access the same collection from different devices!